# Pass additional information back through postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net, postback, image-uploading

I am having trouble using JQuery with ASP.net.  I have a HTML `img`, an `asp:Button` and an `asp:FileUpload`.

```
<img src="images/12345.png" data-id="12345" />
<asp:FileUpload ID="fup" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" />
```

I am trying to pass back the picture id from the HTML `img`.  Any idea of how I could push the data element into a `CommandArgument` or something?

I can't have the HTML image runat="server", because I am setting it dynamically client-side.

**Plugins**

I tried using plugins, nothing is really working out the way I had planned:

This one takes multiple files, I need it to be limited to one. Don't need for it to support dragging or anything fancy.  http://valums.com/ajax-upload/

Uploadify uses Flash, trying to shy away from that. http://www.uploadify.com/

This one uses some ugly iframes and stuff, not looking too nice. Also, the spelling mistakes on the site are a little off-putting. http://www.phpletter.com/Demo/AjaxFileUpload-Demo/

If anyone has either a way to do what I'm asking or a slick way to upload new images (with additional parameters supported), it would be greatly appreciated.

**Solution**
Thanks for the answers, I ended up combining the two and using an `asp:HiddenField` running at the server:

Markup:

```
<img id="img" src="images/12345.png" data-id="12345" />
<asp:HiddenField id="hfData" runat="server" />
<asp:FileUpload ID="fup" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" />
```

JQuery:

```
$("#<%= hfData.ClientID %>").val($("#img").data("id"));
```

Codebehind:

```
string pictureID = hfData.Value;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand you correctly, you can use `<input type="hidden" name="data-id" value="12345" />` to get that `data-id` you are looking for.

Comment: This works if the input:hidden is an `asp:HiddenField`  This would not work if it is not running at the server.

Comment: you can also add `runat=server` on the `input` tag.